# Python 'different_locale' bad locale conversion

Tags: python, django

```
conditions = []
for i in range(1, 13):
    with different_locale('lt_LT'):
        conditions.append(calendar.month_name[i])
```

Trying to get all months in my native "Lithuanian" language.
Result of the code :

```
['sausis', 'vasaris', 'kovas', 'balandis', 'geguþë', 'birþelis', 'liepa', 'rugpjûtis', 'rugsëjis', 'spalis', 'lapkritis', 'gruodis']
```

expected result:

```
['sausis', 'vasaris', 'kovas', 'balandis', 'gegužė', 'birželis', 'liepa', 'rugpjūtis', 'rugsėjis', 'spalis', 'lapkritis', 'gruodis']
```

Also tried "lt_LT.UTF-8" but got these results : `'geguÅ¾Ä\x97', 'birÅ¾elis'`

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using django's [`translation.override`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.override) context manager. Here is a docs [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#using-translations-outside-views-and-templates).

I've tried the following script locally and it returned the desired result.

```
import calendar
from django.utils import translation
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
conditions = []
    for i in range(1, 13):
        with translation.override('lt_LT'):
            conditions.append(_(calendar.month_name[i]))
```

Output:

```
['sausis', 'vasaris', 'kovas', 'balandis', 'gegu\xc5\xbe\xc4\x97', 'bir\xc5\xbeelis', 'liepa', 'rugpj\xc5\xabtis', 'rugs\xc4\x97jis', 'spalis', 'lapkritis', 'gruodis']
```

If you print them it yields:

```
sausis
vasaris
kovas
balandis
gegužė
birželis
liepa
rugpjūtis
rugsėjis
spalis
lapkritis
gruodis
```